# Unique statements and FK

Tags: sql

I have to answer this question about UNIQUE statements. In particolar, the question ask me to indicate which is the maximum number of unique statements someone can define on a relation of 5 columns. I suppose that this number should be 5^5. Is this right?
And another question about Foreign Keys ask me whether attribute A for a relation R can be Foreign Key referencing B in relation S, even if A is not primary key for R. I think that because a FK constraint can also include NULL values, an attribute specified as FK referencing a PK on another table shouldn't be a primary key itself. Is it right?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Mathematically it would be 5! (factorial) but that would just be silly.

Comment: Maximal number of *non-trivial* UNIQUE constraints would be another question. My guess would be 10 := (5! / (3! *2!))

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The options are the following: A) 0 ; B) 1; C) 5 ; D) 5^2; E) 2^5 ; F) log5 ; G) 5^5; H) INFINITE; I) NONE OF THOSE. So, the last one should be the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of distinct unique relationships you can define is 2^n - 1.  Basically, any given column can be in or out of the relationship.  The "- 1" is because you cannot define a unique relationship with no columns.

For instance, with three columns, you can have:

- A
- B
- C
- A, B
- A, C
- B, C
- A, B, C

If you think of these as binary numbers, you will see the pattern:

- 100
- 010
- 001
- 110
- 101
- 011
- 111